# Why the mutant group is called X-Men when there are women also in the team?

Tags: marvel, x-men

A team's name defines who they are. The team tiles such as Justice League describes that every member of that very team stands for justice whether they are male or female. Avengers too is an appropriate name as it stands for both men and women who *avenge the innocent people*.

But why the mutant superhero group is called X-Men when there are women too in that very group. why not choose a different name? Does it signify male chauvinism?

Comment: The Uncanny X-People.

Comment: Originally there was only one, Marvel Girl (Jean Grey) who rarely actually went on field missions

Comment: It is a valid question, as women rights are under severe pressure in many parts of the world and superheroes in comics and movies act as role models to people from a young age. Therefore I consider it important to feed them with extreme politically correct information until they are capable of noticing these things consciously. (GI Joe anyone, or Captain Planet?) 
I'm not too sure the question belongs here, unless you specifically want to know if the original creator is old-fashioned and against female paritcipation in any way.

Comment: @JackBNimble - No women? More like unhinged X-people :)

Comment: OK, whoever voted this as "Off topic", was likely on the wrong StackExchange.

Comment: This question has an answer here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14533/21267

Comment: Because X-Men sounded cooler than x-humans? Lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think they use X-**Men** in the sense that "men" relates to the race of Men i.e. the human race, mankind.

Comment: Like you don't say henchpeople rather than henchmen. X-mooks, forward march!